# Why isn't my game ending in a tie?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coding a tic-tac-toe game in pure javascript.

My program correctly checks if either Player1 or Player2 have won. For some reason, it's not able to check if it's a tie though.

I have set a counter called `moveCounter`. After each successful move, the counter is incremented by one. It is not possible for the counter to reach higher than 9.

Below is a function that tests the game's state.

It will check if player1 or player2 has won. It does this fine.

Below you can see I'm attempting to test for a tie. But nothing is happening. The game is just stuck and nothing is being printed to the console aside from the counter which is being incremented in my `placePiece()` function.

I have tried playing around with it and altering the if condition, along with it's position without the function and I'm having no luck so far.

Here's my `gameState()` function:

```
// The game ends when one player has three of their symbols in a row either horizontally, vertically or diagonally.
function gameState() {

    var result;

    //boxes
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1');
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2');
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3');
    var b1 = document.getElementById('b1');
    var b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
    var b3 = document.getElementById('b3');
    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
    var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
    var c3 = document.getElementById('c3');

    //See if Player 1 has won
    if((a1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && a2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && a3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (b1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (b1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (c1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (a1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c1.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (a2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c2.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (a3.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (a1.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-1")) || (a3.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && c1.classList.contains("box-filled-1"))){
        result = "player1"
        return gameOver(result);
    }

    //See if Player 2 has won
    if((a1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && a2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && a3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (b1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (b1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (c1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (a1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c1.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (a2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c2.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (a3.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b3.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (a1.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c3.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) || (a3.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && b2.classList.contains("box-filled-2") && c1.classList.contains("box-filled-2"))){
        result = "player2"
        return gameOver(result);
    }

    //If all of the squares are filled and no players have three in a row the game is a tie.
    if(moveCounter === 9){
        result = "tie";
        console.log("tie");
        return gameOver(result);
    }
};
```

Here's where it gets called:

```
// Players can only click on empty squares. When the player clicks on an empty square, attach the class box-filled-1 (for O) or box-filled-2 (for X) to the square. 
    function placePiece() {
        if(!this.classList.contains("box-filled-1") && !this.classList.contains("box-filled-2")) {
            if(currentPlayer === player1){
                this.classList.add("box-filled-1");

                player1.currentPlayer = false;
                player2.currentPlayer = true;
                currentPlayer = player2;

                currentPlayerFlag();
                gameState();
                moveCounter++;
                console.log(moveCounter);
            } else {
                this.classList.add("box-filled-2");

                player2.currentPlayer = false;
                player1.currentPlayer = true;
                currentPlayer = player1;

                currentPlayerFlag();
                gameState();
                moveCounter++;
                console.log(moveCounter);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: "_After each successful move, the counter is incremented by one_" I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: this is being done in another function, `placePiece()`.

I know it's being incremented as it's printing to the console

Comment: Can you post the code that shows moveCounter being incremented, and where and how gameState() gets called?

Comment: What is moveCounter initialized to? 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you init moveCounter = 0, then move gameState() after incrementing moveCounter

```
moveCounter++;
gameState();
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I miss that